# gradle Exec: how to get administrator privilege on windows

Tags: gradle, windows-10, exec, root, elevated-privileges

On windows 10,

```
task runTest(type: Exec) {
     workingDir "$buildDir/test"
     commandLine "cmd", "/c", "test.bat"
}
```

The test.bat needs Admin Privilege to edit windows Registry. How to get the privilege?

Comment: Maybe some of these can help you: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3436-run-administrator-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Another useful link: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/elevated-privileges-windows

Comment: not working well with gradle. The test.bat is filtered and copied to to the build test directory every time. The best way is an option like "/admin".